# Package by feature with Spring

Tags: java, spring

There are some discussion about the topic package by feature vs package by layer (https://dzone.com/articles/package-your-classes-feature) but so far I didn't find a precise reply about Spring. There are also in some videos speaking about Spring (https://youtu.be/1FhF-qJwLrI?t=1m26s).

My question is: is really better using package by feature with Spring?
Some annotations in Spring are package based (like @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages ="mypackage.repositories"). In this case would not be worse using a package by feature approach?